# Velocity distribution for Molecular beam vs. gas

Tags: thermodynamics, atomic-physics, laser, probability, spectroscopy

In the book: https://g.co/kgs/JRBLeA (Atomic Physics by C.J. Foot) on page 152 there's a table in the end that compares gas' velocity distribution and that for a molecular beam. I am unable to account for the extra velocity/speed factor in the latter. 
[image]

I understand that the former has a Maxwell Boltzmann distribution.
The text mention, on the same page, that this extra factor is attributed to the observation that faster atoms a more likely to effuse through a hole of area A compared to slower atoms. I don't understand why this should be so. First of all, if you have an atom beam (say) traveling with a particular velocity, how do you associate the concept of temperature to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably know how to derive an expression for the pressure in the context of the [kinetic gas theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases).  If we use this line of argument, but we were interested only in the collisions between the molecules and the small area (=hole) within the wall, we have to ask: If a particle exists the hole during the time interval $[0, dt]$, **where does it come from**?

Assuming that the particle has velocity $v$, and that no collision takes place in the time interval $[0, dt]$ the particles must come from the volume which is ${\bf ds} = {\bf v}\cdot dt$ away from the hole. Or, more precisely, they must come from a volume $V = {\bf A} \cdot {\bf ds} = A \, v dt \cdot \cos{\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the angle of the veclocity to the normal direction of the hole. The key point here is that **particles with a "larger" velocity are allowed to be further way** at time $t=0s$. Thus, "very fast" particles have a non-zero probability to exit the hole, no matter where they are at time $t=0s$, while "slow" particles must come from the direct surrounding of the hole. Proper derivations can be found in statistical physics textbooks.

> [...] if you have an atom beam [...] traveling with a particular velocity, how do you associate the concept of temperature to this?

If we take about a gas having temperature $T$ we implicitly assume a **random** velocity distribution, where the atoms possess different velocities. Also, temperature uses the concept of an **ensemble** of particles -- we are unable to associate a temperature with a single particle, which happens to have the kinetic energy $k_B T$. So, if we use a velocity filter to generate a beam of particles with the velocity range $v + [0, dv]$, we should not use the term temperature to describe it.
However, it is conceptional fine to use the small hole in the wall of the container to generate a beam of particles, which is used probe the distribution of the ensemble inside the container.

Comment: Thank you! I think it makes sense now.